# Migrating data from Title field to Occupation event using Gramps?

Tags: gramps

When I started using Gramps (older versions 3 & 4) for my family tree, I chose to use the Title field to store their occupation information. Gramps since version 5 offers the capability to print the last occupation event in the relationship graph so I decided to migrate my existing data to a proper occupation event. As I have 900+ persons in my family tree, I would like to automate the process. 
Here is how I plan to do things:

1. query the persons database to get the title field data as well as the person id
2. process this data to a nice input file (I need to reformat the title  information as sometimes I recorded several jobs at once)
3. create occupation events from my input file

I am familiar with python and programming in general but I don't know how to interact with Gramps files. Are there example code or documentation I could use to understand how data is organised?

Better ideas accepted.

EDIT
Note : I am currently using v5.0.1

After some research, I know how to do the step 1 above: by using the export menu I can generate a csv where I can find the title and the person id straigth-away. 
Step 2 is just me cleaning the data so that's ok. However for step 3, 
I am stuck. It looks like I could use the import feature if I was able to generate an xml file in the same format as Gramps. The problem is that Gramps expects something like this:

```
<person handle="_cd284dd52627d55ab80" change="1554508105" id="I0010">
  ...
  <eventref hlink="_e235f0096da3481aebdc5bf0138" role="Primary"/>
  ...
</person>
<event handle="_e235f0096da3481aebdc5bf0138" change="1554508051" id="E1346">
  <type>Occupation</type>
  <dateval val="1892"/>
  <description>Teacher</description>
</event>
```

And I have no clue on how to generate the `handle`, `change` and `hlink` values so that they don't break Gramps database. I also don't know what happens if I import partial information, does it break the other data?

Comment: For the sake of clarity for readers in the future, please add to your question exactly which version of Gramps 5 you have installed. If the  Gramps Wiki: https://gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php and the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramps did not have enough information to answer your question, please let us know why.  If you solve the problem, feel free to post a self-answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could find examples of GRAMP xml files here :
https://github.com/gramps-project/gramps/blob/maintenance/gramps50/example/gramps/example.gramps

For details about handle, hlink, etc. They have a great wiki.
In particular, for the handle (time+random number used to identify event), you can look here:
https://www.gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php/Using_database_API#Handles

P.S.: In particular, I would start looking here https://www.gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php?title=Using_database_API